Simplifying equations using regex in Python
I want to write a function in Python that takes any multivariable quadratic equation and then simplifies it as much as possible. For example, the following equation:
(24*x + 1 + 9) / (((8 * 6 * 2) + 1) * y) = 3 + 9 + (3 * (8 + 6)) * 18.56
Convert to the following equation:
(24*x + 10)/(97*y) = 791.52
I was able to make it identify the variables using regex in Python, but it didn't help much to simplify the equation:
r'[a-zA-Z]+\d*'
I also wrote a code to identify numbers and mathematical symbols to separate them from variables and then simplify them with the eval function. But the regex code was not working properly:
r'\(?([-+/*]?\d+\.\d+|\d+[-+/*]?)+\)?'
For example, instead of identifying part 3 + 9 + (3 * (8 + 6)) * 18.56 on the right side of the initial equation, this code identified parts ['9+', '3*', '6', '*18.56'].
If anyone knows the problem of this regex or knows a better way to simplify the equations, please tell me.
I don't want to use additional libraries like sympy, I want to write this program myself.

Regular expressions can help you identify pieces of the equation. However, for simplification, you need to evaluate and reduce the expressions correctly, which is beyond the capabilities of regex.

Regex are not usually used for nested capabilities.

You say " I want to write this program myself." So? What seems to be the problem?

Do you know another way to simplify equations in Python? @user70

Do you know another way to simplify equations in Python? @Bharel

@ArianNa no I don't know

Need to write an LL parser or use libraries as in the answers

You could take an approach where the aim is to just call eval on the input string and prepare the environment so that this evaluation will give you the desired result. This is possible, because:

The names of the variables (x,  y) can be defined as "smart" objects
Python offers ways to override operators so that you can define what it means to add/subtract/multiply/divide/compare such objects
You can use __str__ to convert the evaluated object to the desired output format

To dynamically create the variables of the first step, it will be handy to have them as keys in a dictionary, and associate to them the "smart" objects. Then convert the input string so that these dictionary keys are accessed.
As = is not the equality operator in Python syntax, it would be good to replace any occurrence of that by "==".
Here is code you could start with. It would need extension if you need to support more operators, or need smarter simplification rules to be applied, but this will already deal with the example you have provided:
class Operator:
    symbol = "?"  # Subclass should override this
    order = 100   # Subclass should override this (operator precedence) 
    
    def __init__(self, left, right=None):
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    @staticmethod
    def wrap(expr, order=0):
        return str(expr)
    
    def __mul__(self, other):
        return Product(self, other)

    __rmul__ = __mul__
    
    def __truediv__(self, other):
        return Quotient(self, other)

    def __rtruediv__(self, other):
        return Quotient(other, self)

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Sum(self, other)

    __radd__ = __add__

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return Difference(self, other)

    def __rsub__(self, other):
        return Difference(other, self)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return Equality(self, other)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.wrap(self.left, self.order)} {self.symbol} {self.wrap(self.right, self.order)}"

class BinaryOperator(Operator):
    @staticmethod
    def wrap(expr, order=0):
        # Wrap in parentheses if this operator-expression is used as an operand
        #    of an operator that has higher precedence (lower order)
        if isinstance(expr, BinaryOperator) and expr.order > order:
            return f"({expr})"
        return str(expr)


class Variable(Operator):
    order = 0
    def __str__(self):
        return self.left
    

class Product(BinaryOperator):
    order = 10
    symbol = "*"
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        if isinstance(a, Product):  # Rotate tree to potentially simplify
            a, b = a.left, a.right * b
        super().__init__(a, b)
        
class Sum(BinaryOperator):
    order = 20
    symbol = "+"
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        if isinstance(a, Sum):  # Rotate tree to potentially simplify
            a, b = a.left, a.right + b
        super().__init__(a, b)

class Difference(BinaryOperator):
    order = 20
    symbol = "-"

class Quotient(BinaryOperator):
    order = 10
    symbol = "/"

class Equality(BinaryOperator):
    order = 30
    symbol = "="


import re
def simplify(s):
    # Replace single "=" with double ("==")
    s = re.sub(r"(?<!=)=(?!=)", "==", s)
    # Identify all variable names
    regex = r"[a-zA-Z]\w*"
    # Map each name to a Variable instance
    d = { name: Variable(name) for name in re.findall(regex, s) }
    # Alter variable names into attributes of this dict
    s = re.sub(regex, r"d['\g<0>']", s)
    return eval(s)


# demo
s = "(24*x + 1 + 9) / (((8 * 6 * 2) + 1) * y) = 3 + 9 + (3 * (8 + 6)) * 18.56"
print(simplify(s)) # (x * 24 + 10) / y * 97 = 791.52

This is just a start. You'll need to add simplification rules as you tailor this solution to your needs.

Can you please explain the code you wrote and what it does? I tested the code and, for example, it did't convert the expression 2*x + 2 + x into 3*x + 2. Can it be implemented to add the variables together to make the expression simpler?

As I wrote in my answer: "Here is code you could start with. It would need extension if you need to support more operators, or need smarter simplification rules to be applied".

So, sure you can implement logic to add those variables together, but then there will still be more rules to apply, and more, and more. In the end you'll be rewriting www.wolframalpha.com

Can you please give me some guidance and help to implement mathematical operators for variables? I don't know what to do exactly

This can get complex. If you stick to polynomial expressions in a few variables, then research how to add or multiply polynomial expressions. But this is just a subset of possibilities. You could have multiplications of x with y, or raise x to a rational power (like x ^ 1.5), or even x ^ y, ... All these expressions follow specific rules on how to optimise them, ...etc. This is too broad. If you have a specific question about some limited form of expression, then ask a specific, new question about it.

Edit: Aaaand now I see your last sentence... Whatever. I'll leave this in case it helps someone else in the future.
Is this homework? If not, then I say abandon the approach entirely because it's too painful and there are better tools for the job.
Speaking of better tools, check out SymPy.simplify.
from sympy import simplify, symbols

# The equation that we want to simplify
# (24*x + 1 + 9) / (((8 * 6 * 2) + 1) * y) = 3 + 9 + (3 * (8 + 6)) * 18.56

# Set up our symbols so SymPy knows what it's working with. 
x, y = symbols('x y')

# Define both sides of the equation
left = (24*x + 1 + 9) / (((8 * 6 * 2) + 1) * y)
right = "3 + 9 + (3 * (8 + 6)) * 18.56" # This is a string so Python doesn't simplify it for us

# This wheel already exists.
left_simplified = simplify(left)
right_simplified = simplify(right)

# Print the results
print(f"The equation:   {left} = {right}")
print(f"simplifies to:  {left_simplified} = {right_simplified:.2f}")

The output:
The equation:   (24*x + 10)/(97*y) = 3 + 9 + (3 * (8 + 6)) * 18.56
simplifies to:  2*(12*x + 5)/(97*y) = 791.52

